# How to draw bitmap as OpenGL texture in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, bitmap, textures

I have a bitmap, and its handle (Win32 HBITMAP). Any suggestion of how to draw this bitmap on an OpenGL quad (with scaling and pulling the 4 corners of the bitmap to fit the 4 vertexes of the quad)?

Comment: Often asked question, check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271310/opengl-texturing-a-cube that actually asks how to apply a bitmap on a face of a cube, eg a quad.

Comment: @Kheldar that's a bit different matter there, though closely related..

Comment: "pulling the 4 corners of the bitmap" here i mean making the bitmap no longer rectangular, to fit the quad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to retrieve the data contained in the HBITMAP, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx Then you can upload the DIB data to OpenGL using *glTexImage2D* or *glTexSubImage2D*

With a texture being created you can apply this like usual (enable texturing, give each corner of the quad a texture coordinate).

**EDIT due to comment**

This (untested!) code should do the trick

```
GLuint load_bitmap_to_texture(
    HDC device_context, 
    HBITMAP bitmap_handle, 
    bool flip_image) /* untested */
{
    const int BytesPerPixel = sizeof(DWORD);

    SIZE bitmap_size;
    if( !GetBitmapDimensionEx(bitmap_handle, &bitmap_size) )
        return 0;

    ssize_t bitmap_buffer_size = bitmap_size.cx * bitmap_size.cy * BytesPerPixel;

#ifdef USE_DWORD
    DWORD *bitmap_buffer;
#else
    void *bitmap_buffer;
#endif
    bitmap_buffer = malloc(bitmap_buffer_size);

    if( !bitmap_buffer )
        return 0;


    BITMAPINFO bitmap_info;
    memset(&bitmap_info, 0, sizeof(bitmap_info));
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth  = bitmap_size.cx;
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = bitmap_size.cy;
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = BitsPerPixel;
    bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    if( flip_image ) /* this tells Windows where to set the origin (top or bottom) */
        bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight *= -1;

    if( !GetDIBits(device_context, 
                   bitmap_handle, 
                   0, bitmap_size.cy, 
                   bitmap_buffer, 
                   &bitmap_info,
                   DIB_RGB_COLORS /* irrelevant, but GetDIBits expects a valid value */ )
     ) {
        free(bitmap_buffer);
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint texture_name;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_name);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_name);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_FALSE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST,  GL_TRUE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
                 bitmap_size.cx, bitmap_size.cy, 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
#ifdef USE_DWORD
                 GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,
#else
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
#endif
                 bitmap_buffer);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    free(bitmap_buffer);

    return texture_name;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between DIB & BMP? aint they the same?

Comment: Windows offers to create a DC on a DIBSECTION. DIBSECTIONs are essentially DIB files in memory. DIB files are what you find as .BMP in the file system, but that doesn't matter. The important thing is, that you can make Windows to operate on some memory in your process' address space, from where you can pass it to further APIs. However if you just want to read a BMP file, than going through a HBITMAP is a overly complicated method. You can load it directly. BMP files are rather simple to read.

Comment: my HBITMAP is actually a screenshot, so just can't load it as a BMP file. tks for the link you provided to GetDIBits function. however, the description about this function on MSDN is a bit not so clear. the buffer to receive DIB data must be passed in, but how much memory should be allocated for this DIB data is a question, you have any idea to allocate memory for DIB data?

Comment: to daten: help! the texture rendered is upside down. color is inverted. possibly caused by GL_RGBA or GL_BGRA?

Comment: fixed by changing the coordinates in glTexCoord

Comment: @Paul: I'm surprised the texture was flipped, DIBs have their origin in the lower, left, too IIRC. Anyway, you don't need to adjust the texture coordinates. Instead use a negative number in the BITMAPINFOHEADER: `bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bitmap_size.cy;` which tells Windows to flip the image.

Comment: did you mean "GL_RGBA" or "GL_BGRA" in the call to glTexImage2D? because i'm afraid that blue & red are swapped

Comment: @Paul: Originally I had it GL_BGRA, since that's the internal format Windows uses for DIBs. If the channels are flipped use GL_BGRA. Also you could try GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV instead of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE; and a DWORD* instead of void* since that's the types Windows uses internally.

Comment: my VC++ "gl.h" is quite ancient, i had to use "GL_BGR_EXT" instead of "GL_BGR" :)

Comment: @Paul: My recommendation: Get GLEW, use GL/glew.h instead of GL/gl.h, don't forget to call glewInit() after context creation.